# Is it possible to use web.config from other app in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, web-config

I have my asp.net web site. This web site is part of another big application that has its own `web.config`. Is it possible to force my web site use this `web.config`?

For example, root application with `web.config`:

```
C:\RootApp\web.config
```

And nested web site:

```
C:\RootApp\SomeFolder\NestedWebSite
```

I want `NestedWebSite` to use root `web.config`.

Note: `NestedWebSite` is complete `ASP.NET WebSite`

Comment: `web.config` files cascade down. So a `web.config` in **NestedWebSite** will override the one from the parent (**RootApp**) as it is more specific.

Comment: You can get some valuable insights [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1671270.aspx?app+config+machine+config+web+config)

Comment: @Belogix It will not completey override, it will merge. If if have duplicate keys it will complain.

Comment: @VitorCanova - I meant to highlight "cascade down" more so than "override". My thought process being that it is like CSS in the way it inherits but a more specific is used if possible.

Comment: @Belogix Oh, sorry. Now I get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look how **[ASP.NET Configuration File Hierarchy and Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)** works. More specifically the **[Scope of Configuration Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#scope_of_configuration_settings)** section.

Basically it cascade (like `Belogix` pointed out) the configurations follow how the virtual directory is configured.

```
WebSiteRootApp
---->AnotherNestedWebSite
-------->EvenMoreNestedWebSite   
---->NestedWebSite
```

In this example the `NestedWebSite` will inherit all config above (according the links I provided). But in this example I want to point that it will inherit your `WebSiteRootApp` config.

In the `EvenMoreNestedWebSite` example it will inherit its "father" and "grampa" too, in this case `AnotherNestedWebSite` and  `WebSiteRootApp`.

Some configurations maybe you will not want to inherit so you can avoid this with this example:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="connectionString" value="sample value"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

In the above example I can specify that `EvenMoreNestedWebSite` needs to forget all configurations in that section it inherit and use just the one provided.